# Two inequalities imply third?

Tags: inequality

I'm spinning my wheels here - I was able to figure out the solution to my previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986704/constructing-lyapunov-function-for-system-of-odes, but need help on the finishing touch.

$$\mathrm{Does} \ \ \dfrac{\tau+1}{\mu+\mu_T}<1, \dfrac{\beta(1+\dfrac{1}{\tau})}{\mu+\mu_A}<1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{(\beta+\tau)(1+\dfrac{1}{\tau})}{\mu+\mu_T+\mu_A}<1?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

Let $\tau, \beta, \mu = 10$ and $\mu_T = \mu_A = 2$. Then
$$\frac {10+1} {10+2} = \frac {10(1+1/10)} {10+2} = \frac {11} {12} < 1,$$
but $$\frac {(10+10)(1+1/10)} {10+2+2} = \frac{22}{14} > 1$$

Comment: good, i too was thinking of an example, but u r fast. +1